# How can i save arrays and print them on C++

Tags: c++, oop

How can i save arrays and print them in c++,here's what i mean, i am creating a student database, and in one class i am giving the students name, surname, id, age, etc. So how can i save them and print those information that i have given. Here is what i have tried so far, and it hasn't been working any body have any ideas?

```
#ifndef Student_h
#define Student_h

class Student
{
public:
    virtual void Print() = 0;
};
#endif

#include "Student.h"
#ifndef University_h
#define University_h

class University :public Student
{
private:
    string University_Name;
public:
    
    University(string Uni);
    void Set_University_Name(string University);
    string Get_University_Name();
    void Print();
};
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"University.h"
#include"Student.h"
using namespace std;

University::University(string Uni)
{
    Set_University_Name(Uni);
}
void University::Set_University_Name(string U_Name)
{
    University_Name = U_Name;
}
string University::Get_University_Name()
{
    return University_Name;
}
void University::Print()
{
    cout << "\n South East European University" << University_Name;
}

class Data_Base
{
private:
    string Student_Name;
    string Student_Surname;
    string Course;
    int Student_Age;
    int Student_ID;
public:

    void Set_Name(string Name);
    string Get_Name();
    void Set_Surname(string Surname);
    string Get_Surname();
    void Set_Course(string _Course);
    string Get_Course();
    void Set_Age(int Age);
    int Get_Age();
    void Set_ID(int ID);
    int Get_ID();
    void Print();
    void Print_Data();
    double Average();
};

void Data_Base::Print(){

    int  n = 0;
    cout << "\n Enter how many students you wish to add: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "\n Student:" << i + 1 << endl;
        cout << "\n Enter Student Name:";
        cin >> Student_Name;
        cout << "\n Enter Student Surname:";
        cin >> Student_Surname;
        cout << "\n What Course is the Student Studying:";
        cin >> Course;
        cout << "\n Enter Student Age:";
        cin >> Student_Age;
        cout << "\n Enter Student ID:";
        cin >> Student_ID;
    }
}

void Data_Base::Print_Data(){

    cout << "Student Data Base: " << endl;{
        cout << "\n Student Name :" << Student_Name;
        cout << "\n Course :" << Course;
        cout << "\n ID : " << Student_ID;
    }
}
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"Student.h"
#include"University.h"
#include"DataBase.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int Menu;
    Data_Base add, view, average;
    
    

    Data_Base* AddStudent = &add;
    Data_Base* ViewStudents = &view;
    Data_Base* AverageGrade = &average;
    
menu:
    cout << "\n===========================" << endl;
    cout << "\n Press - 1 - To Add New Students";
    cout << "\n Press - 2 - To View Added Students";
    cout << "\n Press - 3 - To To Find the Average Grade";
    cout << "\n Press - 0 - To Quit Program";
    cout << "\n ----Please Select An Option----";
    cin >> Menu;

    switch (Menu)
    {
    case 1:
        AddStudent->Print();
        break;
    case 2:
        ViewStudents->Print_Data();
        break;
    case 3:
        AverageGrade->Average();
        break;
    case 0:
        return 0;
        cout << "\n Thank You for Using our Program!";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\n Wrong Button!Try Again";
        goto menu;
        break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text in the question, not as an image.

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: sorry guys!! i fixed it

Comment: you'll probably want a `vector` of students, initialized to size `n`, then loop through and add information for each one. You can have methods for printing the entire vector of students and a singular student. Not much to say beyond that, you haven't included much in terms of your approach so far, definitions for your variables, what's not working, etc. What you've posted looks promising, but please edit your question with an [mre] and explain what you mean by "it hasn't been working"

Comment: Persistence is a whole topic on its own. You can use simple text based files (e.g. std::fstream which works the same as std::cout) or extensive as using SQLite. Also using e.g. a class Student would help here.

Comment: by "it hasnt been working" i mean when i try to print the information, it will not print anything, i'll try and use this method that you suggest

Comment: IMHO, this is not OOP.  To make it more OOP, you would have the database that contains (aggregate) zero or more Students.  Each Student would contain a name, course and ID.  The Student class would have an interface to input its members from an input stream and likewise an interface to write to a stream.

Comment: You've got a recursive `#include` issue.  The end of `student.h` contains a `#include "student.h"`.  There also is not a matching `#endif` for `#ifndef Student_h`.

Comment: Another OOP issue.  Last time I checked, a University is-not-a Student.  A University does not extend or specialize a Student (violation of inheritance/generalization).  A University **has-a** or **has-none** Students (aggregation).  So, University does not have a Student ID.  It may have a name, but I don't think having a name warrants inheritance.  Think of the University as `std::vector<Student>`.

Comment: You should post compilable code.  There is a `#include "Student.h"` before `#ifndef University_h"` is this correct?  This means that `Student.h` will always be included whenever `University.h` is included.

Comment: Hints: 1) Pass strings by reference or constant reference to prevent the compiler from making copies. 2) Use initializer lists with constructors, don't call a method.  Make your program easier for the compiler to optimize. :-)

Comment: thanks for the help guys: )

Comment: Why are you using pointers in the `switch` statement?  Have you tried `add.Print();` for `case` 1?

Comment: P.s: sorry for the code issues, technical problems.

Comment: Also, don't put code after a `return` statement.  The execution literally leaves the function (returns) when encountering a `return` statement.  Thus no code following a `return` statement will be executed.

Comment: Yes i have tried, but idk, it just came to my attention to use pointers.

Comment: Talk with your instructor about the `goto` statement.  You could use a `while` or `do-while` statement instead.

Comment: Don't use pointers.  Don't use pointers.  Only use pointers when there are no other alternatives; then use a smart pointer.  Or use pointers when you really need them and you completely understand the consequences.  Remember:  pointers can point to anywhere, including invalid locations.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int Menu;
    Data_Base db;
    
    
menu:
    cout << "\n===========================" << endl;
    cout << "\n Press - 1 - To Add New Students";
    cout << "\n Press - 2 - To View Added Students";
    cout << "\n Press - 3 - To To Find the Average Grade";
    cout << "\n Press - 0 - To Quit Program";
    cout << "\n ----Please Select An Option----";
    cin >> Menu;

    switch (Menu)
    {
    case 1:
        db.Print();
        break;
    case 2:
        db.Print_Data();
        break;
    case 3:
        db.Average();
        break;
    case 0:
        return 0;
        cout << "\n Thank You for Using our Program!";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\n Wrong Button!Try Again";
        goto menu;
        break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This should let you see one student after you added it. As mentioned in the comments, you will need a list in order to store multiple students in the same database. Also it was wrong to use three diferent Data_base objects hoping for them to have the same private members becouse they have different memory unless they point to the same object.